# regex to match contents of last [bracketed text]

Tags: php, regex

Target string:

> Come to the castle [Mario], I've baked
>   you [a cake]

I want to match the contents of the last brackets, ignoring the other brackets ie

> a cake

I'm a bit stuck, can anyone provide the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
\[([^[\]]*)][^[]*(?:\[[^\]]*)?$
```

- **`\[([^[\]]*)]`** matches any sequence of `[…]` that does not contain `[` or `]`;
- **`[^[]*`** matches any following characters that are not `[` (i.e. the begin of another potential group of `[…]`);
- **`(?:\[[^\]]*)?$`** matches a potential single `[` that is not followed by a closing `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, uses a negative look ahead assertion

```
\[[^\[]*\](?!\[)$
```

Comment: `(?!\[)$` is always true as there cannot be a `[` after the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of a look-ahead.  And because we don't know the precise nature of what text/characters will have to be processed, it could look something like this, but it will need a little work:

```
\[[a-z\s]*\](?!.*\[([a-z\s]*)\])
```

Your contents should be matched in \1, or possibly \2.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is best: `.*\[(.*?)]` will do what you want; with nested brackets it will return the last, innermost one and ignore bad nesting. There's no need for a negative character class: the `.*?` makes sure you don't have any right brackets in the match, and since the `.*` makes sure you match at the last possible spot, it also keeps out any 'outer' left brackets.