# Regex to match last paragraph tag and contents

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will remove the last paragraph tags in a string, and all the content between. I can match the paragraph tags fine, but not the last..

Example:

```
<p>This shouldnt get selected</p>
<p>This either</p>
<p>Bleh</p>
```

What should get matched

```
<p>Bleh</p>
```

I found some code that matched the last set of square brackets here, [regex to match contents of last [bracketed text]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204000/regex-to-match-contents-of-last-bracketed-text) , but have been unable to modify it to work with paragraph tags.

Comment: Use a HTML parser. See [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: What should it do if there are nested paragraph tags?

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression using lookahead will work:

```
<p>(.*?)</p>(?!\s*<p>)
```